# Conditional inclusion of files in maven

Tags: java, build, maven-3, java-ee-6

I have a JEE6 web application project.The project structure is according to maven convention.

Now I have introduced additional web.xml files for this project.

So they are now stored in WEB-INF as below:

WEB-INF/

```
     |__ A/web.xml

     |__ B/web.xml
```

What is the maven way to build a war to include proper xml depending upon the property.

I know the how to add custom properties in maven.But I cannot find how to configure the maven plugin such that during the war file building it chooses the appropriate file.

Any hints/suggestions/maven best practices in such cases are most welcome.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[maven war plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin) could be configured to add and filter some external resources. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html.

So I would make 2 maven [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) with 2 war plugin configuration like this :

```
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
          <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/__A</directory>
          <includes>
            <include>web.xml</include>
          </includes>
          <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <!-- repeat for your second profile -->
```

BUT I think a better solution (and if your project permits it) would be to keep only one web.xml file with some filtered properties inside. In this case, you should just configure your war plugin to enable some filtering like this :

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```